# how to pass the user and pwd via the runtime.exec() in java

Tags: java, sh, solaris, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run a simple command using java 1.8  and OS Solaris 11.
My program runs under a particular user and the command must run under SuperUser

here is the command:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su - root -c 'pargs -l 1111'");`

if i run the command in shall its work fine and ask for password and wen i enter the password i will get the result.

the problem is wen i run it in java 
here is my code

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su - root -c 'pargs -l 1111'");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
out.println(password);
out.flush();
int exitCode= proc.waitFor();
System.out.println(exitCode);//exitCode = 1
BufferedReader pArgs= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
if((line=pArgs.readLine()) != null)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //something not working = ERROR 
}
```

i think that the line equal to null because something  in the set of the password is not correct bat i'm not sure

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Java has the ability to examine processes: `Optional<String[]> processArgs = ProcessHandle.of(1111).info().arguments();`  You may be able to do this even without root privileges, depending on the owner of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all the answers. But my solution was a little different.
It was decided to use an external file that could be written and read from both processes.
The whole goal was to do a handshake again in case the process running at the root will fall (watchdog).

So now there is no need to use the command

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su - root -c 'pargs -l 1111'");
```

When the root process starts running, it records a time signature into a file.
and if the process of the user (who reads the file every X time) finds that the signature has changed, he will do a handshake again.

Answer (score 4):

I might suggest a different way around this issue altogether.  Instead of trying to run a shell command that dynamically asks for a password, make the command not require a password.

If its just asking for a password because it needs root, you can add a line in the sudoers file under root to say that your program user is allowed to execute that one specific command as if they were root:  https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-linux-sudoers-file.

This would be more secure too as you wouldn't have the password floating around code.

Comment: I think its in Solaris 11 by default.  You might have to install it to 9 or 10.  https://serverfault.com/questions/234456/where-is-the-sudoers-file-on-solaris

Answer (score 2):

> how to pass the user and pwd via the runtime.exec() in java

You can't under Solaris if you want to use `su`.

[Solaris `su`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/su/su.c) uses [the `getpass()` function](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/port/stdio/getpass.c) to get the necessary password from the user.

From [the Solaris `getpass()` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37843/getpass-3c.html):

> **Description**
>
> The `getpass()` function opens the process's controlling terminal, writes to that device the null-terminated string `prompt`, disables echoing, reads a string of characters up to the next newline character or EOF, restores the terminal state and closes the terminal.
>
> ...
>
> **Errors**
>
> The `getpass()` and `getpassphrase()` functions may fail if:
>
> ...
>
> `ENXIO`
>
> The process does not have a controlling terminal.

`su` will either get the password from the controlling terminal, or it will fail.

This is a deliberate design decision to make it almost impossible to perform insecure actions such as automated password entry.

Comment: so what can i do?
i need to find process that run under root from process that run under defrent user how can i do it?